# Import CSV and random output rows 6 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some names in a `names.csv` file. Now I want to output 6 random names (of the winners) to the console and to a new, `winner.csv` file.

I already tried different for loops, but somehow I just can't make it work. It works however with just 1 output.

```
import csv
import random

winners = []

with open('names.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in reader:
    chosen_row1 = random.choice((list(reader)))
    winners.append(chosen_row1[0])
    print(chosen_row1[0])

with open('winner.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    winnerwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    winnerwriter.writerow(winners)
```

I like to export a `x` amount of names.

Comment: are you getting output in the console of chosen_row1[0] different everytime?

Comment: @vbrises yes, the output changes. But it's only one and I need 6 outputs of all different names. This code works, but it just gives me one output, which is everytime a different one.

Comment: i guess, it is reading only 1 line in the reader or considering whole file as 1 line, since your newline='', you should check size of reader after you read it.

Comment: I just tried to delete newline="" and added chosen_row & winners.append. but now I get this: IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. It uses `random.sample` (which returns multiple items) rather than `random.choice`, which just returns one.

```
import csv
import random

winners = []
number_of_winners = 0 # number of winners
with open('tester.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        winners.append(row[0])

winner_selection = random.sample(winners, number_of_winners)

with open('winner.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    winnerwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    winnerwriter.writerow(winner_selection)
```

Comment: That is actually the solution for my problem. Thank you! This works exactly as I need it.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help. If this solution fits your needs, kindly click the checkmark to the left of my answer so that everyone knows the problem is resolved.